# Display all declared clocks and their frequency

Tags: linux, clock

I would like to know how to display all clocks and their associated driver in Linux. It is possible to do it by looking at the device tree file but I was wondering if there is a sysfs entry that allows to print clock tree. 
Is it possible to know the frequency of each clock also ? 
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use `debugfs`. Mount it under `/sys/kernel/debug` and all the probed clocks are shown in `/sys/kernel/debug/clk`.

https://processors.wiki.ti.com/index.php/Clock_Framework_User_Guide#Clock_tree_from_debugfs